# handle 12GB data upload in Play Framework?

Tags: http, playframework-2.0

I am trying to upload a file of size 12GB ,my RAM size is  4GB so ,i am able to upload only 2GB files i am not getting any idea on how to proceed further. Any help is highly appreciable

Comment: It probably could depend on the operating systems (and processors), both on the client side (your laptop) and on the server side. Some 32 bits filesystems limit size to 2Gbytes. Try using 64 bits operating systems (and JVMs). BTW, are you sure you have the bandwidth and time to upload such a big file. Can't you split it into smaller pieces (e.g. using [csplit](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucsplit.htm) or some equivalent).

Comment: but i want to divide it using my program so that once i upload the smaller files i can merge it into single file as it was in the initial stage.any idea?

Comment: Yes it is possible to merge several files (e.g. obtained by splitting) into one. On Posix systems you'll use the [cat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) command.

Comment: yes i too know this but what i asked you is i want it to be done automatically ,i mean my application will ask the user to select a file to upload then the application will divide it and then upload it, after upload is done it merge it again into a single file.any idea on this?

Comment: I believe you have a wrong approach and a wrong design. Consumer users should not even expect to upload a 12Gb file without great pain (and a lot of time, that they don't have).

Comment: may be but because i am struck here so could you provide me some information on how to split it using a code in the program

Comment: possible duplicate of [uploading a 15 Gb file and downloading it in playframework for java.is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086449/uploading-a-15-gb-file-and-downloading-it-in-playframework-for-java-is-it-possib)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, send it by FTP or a Javascript/AJAX uploader instead.

HTTP is not a good protocol to choose for this.. the filesize is ridiculously far beyond the known limitations of HTTP servers and gateways. The server has to buffer the upload before it can be handled, and your filesize will exceed most known buffers.

HTTP uploads are often expected to handle 5MB - 50MB and limited in the 5MB - 200MB range. Proxy servers & network infrastructure will likely also impose their own limits.

See also: [What is the maximum file size I can transfer using HTTP? And using FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461282/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-i-can-transfer-using-http-and-using-ftp)

Comment: any idea how to do upload 12Gb data using FTP or javascript?

Comment: Don't upload 12Gb data. Sell the service of loading a pack of DVDs (or a hard disk, or an SSD, or a USB key) containing them.