# what's the max file size when sending files to server over HTTP while using A tags and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

It looks like there is a file size limit while using a tags(download property)+ Formdata. If so, what's the max size of it? Does it have something to do with browsers? like I can modify browser to change the max size

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461282/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-i-can-transfer-using-http-and-using-ftp

Comment: There is no limit, I would assume it depends on what restrictions the server has. For example, setting the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in the `php.ini` of the server. This isn't something that can be done in the browser, only the server side.

Comment: Yes we did set the max size in server side to 100M, so I'd assume it doesn't have max limit on browser